# Oracle SQL - Using CASE WHEN to select a proper date field

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a complicated problem and I cannot for the life of me figure out the logic in my head.

I am trying to tackle the issue of building a query reporting the proper dates for a material event. Essentially, my company is trying to track inventory management by seeing when we buy (quantity+) a part, when we manufacture (quantity+) a part, when we sell (quantity-) a part, or when we use that part to build a higher assembly part (quantity-).

The table structures I am working with look like this: 
[image]

Where there can be 4 types of events, each having their own unique identifier, and each having a date on which that event occurs.

I then have the "Happenings" table, which actually has the list of transactions, that looks like this:
[image]

(Note I have eliminated some irrelevant field names).

What I am trying to accomplish is using a `CASE...WHEN` statement to select the proper date based on if the current line's foreign key.

So something to the effect of:

```
CASE
    WHEN Type = "Purchase Order" THEN (SELECT Date FROM Events WHERE Events.Number = Happenings.PO_ID)
    WHEN TYPE = "Make Order" THEN (SELECT Date FROM Events WHERE Events.Number = Happenings.MO_ID)
    WHEN TYPE = "Sale" THEN (SELECT Date FROM Events WHERE Events.Number = Happenings.Sale_ID)
    WHEN TYPE = "Create Order" THEN (SELECT Date FROM Events WHERE Events.Number = Happenings.CO_ID)
    ELSE NULL AS Event_Date
```

Unfortunately, I cannot post too much data as it is company proprietary, but that is the gist of what I am trying to accomplish; using `CASE...WHEN` to properly select a value from another table when my current row contains the unique identifier.

Comment: If you were to dynamically build the list of foreign keys and then use that to join events then that might be easier. You could also select date from events where events.number IN ('') into a CTE along with a declaration of the type and use that. e.g. `;with cteExample ([PK], [Col], [Date]) as (select h.PO_ID, 'Purchase Order', date from events join happenings h on events.Number = happenings.PO_ID union all select ...) select case when type = "Purchase Order" then a.date where [col] = "Purchase Order" ...

Comment: You don't have to post proprietary data, fake data is fine as long as it is representative - and you show both sample data and the expected result for that data. (Plus your current best effort and what it produces, preferably, so we can see where you are going wrong). See [mcve]. And please post [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) rather than images.

Comment: Is markdown appropriate? I can reformat those tables as such and fill them with bogus (but representative) data @AlexPoole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a case on the join condition

```
select e1.date 
from events e1
inner join happenings h2
on e1.Number = case when e1.type = 'Purchase' then h2.PO_ID
                    when e1.type = 'Make' then h2.MO_ID
                    ...
               end
```

Comment: That's even more direct than my CTE method - might need an 'isnull' handler in the event that no date is returned though.

Comment: How would this work in the condition that there is no date? Would I add an `ELSE`?

Comment: @JerryM Are you saying there will be items in Events with a date but no corresponding `Events.Type`? If so, what would you want to return?

Comment: I do not see that in my current data @JohnHC, but I would like to account for that in the event it occurs. I would think a "NULL" value would be appropriate.

Comment: @JerryM. I'd need to see the wider query, not just this snippet. As this is an `inner join`, in the event of no data, no data is returned.

Comment: I framed the question inappropriately. But, using test data, this is correct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try to use nvl function
for organize Happenings table.
NVL( PO_ID, NVL( MO_ID, NVL(CO_ID, NVL(Sale_ID, 0) ))) AS IDS

then

Events.Number = IDS

hope it helps